# Shared element transition get weird behavior while something is scrolling

Tags: android, transition, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm using shared element transition between activities. The first activity contains a `LinearLayout` and a `RecyclerView`:

[image]

The second activity:

[image]

And here's my code, seems very simple:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) getContext(), pairs);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(getContext(), new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, scheme), options.toBundle());
```

In common cases, everything seems ok, the transition animation works perfectly. But if I start the next activity while the `RecyclerView` in the first activity is scrolling, then go back to the first activity, something terrible happens:

[image]

I also tested `ListView` and `ViewPager`, `ListView` has same problem while `ViewPager` not. If I stop the scroll before `startActivity`, everything will be fine.

However in my product environment, views are complicated and it is ugly to find all `ListView`s and `RecyclerView`s and stop their scrolls. Is there anyway to prevent it from happening other than stop scrolling before `startActivity`?

Comment: Btw, does anyone know how to make the screenshot smaller?

Comment: This is the original url: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwB5R.png` You can use modifiers like `l`, `m`, `s` for large, medium and small and add one of them at the end of the url but before png like this: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwB5Rl.png`

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView class don't have such method to disable scrolling. Create CustomRecyclerView yourself like one below.

```
public class FooRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

   private boolean verticleScrollingEnabled = true;

   public void enableVersticleScroll (boolean enabled) {
       verticleScrollingEnabled = enabled;
   }

   public boolean isVerticleScrollingEnabled() {
       return verticleScrollingEnabled;
   }

   @Override
   public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {

      if (isVerticleScrollingEnabled())
          return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
      return 0;
   }


  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

     if(isVerticleScrollingEnabled())
         return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
     return false;

  }



   public FooRecyclerView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public FooRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public FooRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,        int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }
}
```

replace RecyclerView to above created customview,

```
<com.customGoogleViews.FooRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/task_sub_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

disable scrolling before starting new activity,

```
recyclerview.enableVersticleScroll(false);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) getContext(), pairs);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(getContext(), new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, scheme), options.toBundle());
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm not trying to disable but to *stop* the scrolling just before transition. To do this, just calling `RecyclerView.stopScroll()`. I'm trying to get a more elegant way to solve the problem.